# clang - error: non-ASM statement in naked function is not supported

Tags: clang, inline-assembly, llvm-clang

```
$ clang --version
clang version 5.0.0 (tags/RELEASE_500/final)
```

.

```
CC ../../py/nlrthumb.c
../../py/nlrthumb.c:79:5: error: non-ASM statement in naked function is not supported
    return 0; // needed to silence compiler warning
```

Why doesn't Clang support `non-ASM statement in naked function`?

This works fine on `gcc`.

The [mailing list explains it as](http://lists.llvm.org/pipermail/cfe-commits/Week-of-Mon-20140901/114153.html)

> Naked functions don't have prologues or epilogues, so doing
>   codegen for anything other than inline assembly would be completely
>   hit or miss.

so then how can `gcc` do it?

Comment: http://lists.llvm.org/pipermail/cfe-commits/Week-of-Mon-20140901/114153.html

Comment: @negacao updated question with your info.

Comment: "how can gcc do it" - It [doesn't](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/ARM-Function-Attributes.html#ARM-Function-Attributes).  *Only basic asm statements can safely be included in naked functions. While using extended asm or a mixture of basic asm and C code may appear to work, they cannot be depended upon to work reliably and are not supported.*

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I should have written this as an answer instead of a comment.  The question was:

*Why doesn't Clang support non-ASM statement in naked function?  This works fine on gcc.*

The answer is that this **doesn't** work fine in gcc.  Quoting from the gcc [docs](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/ARM-Function-Attributes.html#ARM-Function-Attributes) for the `naked` attribute:

> Only basic asm statements can safely be included in naked functions. While using extended asm or a mixture of basic asm and C code may appear to work, they cannot be depended upon to work reliably and are not supported.

If there is a less ambiguous way to phrase this, I couldn't come up with it.

Note that while the specific link above is for ARM (which is what I'm guessing the OP is using), I believe the same text applies to all platforms that support `naked`.

Comment: GCC could have thrown an error rather than allow something it knows isn't supported reliably.

Comment: @MichaelPetch - Exactly.  So the question here isn't really "Why does this work in gcc and not in clang?" it's more "Why doesn't gcc give the same highly informative compiler error that clang does for this unsupported usage?"  This may not be what OP wants to hear, but there it is.

Comment: @DavidWohlferd I just wanted clarity. This answer provides it.